# Unable to connect with postgres master docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, database-replication

Tried implementing postgres master-slave replication by following this [blog](https://mgkworks.blogspot.com/2017/06/postgresql-masterslave-steaming.html). Used postgres:9.6 docker image for the implementation. Replication works fine for the changes entered through the master node's console. But the master node can't be accessed from outside. It's showing the following error:

[image]

This error is shown even after the password is assigned for the role 'root'. But a container ran from same docker image (postgres:9.6) without the master-slave configuration is accessible from outside (the host machine where docker daemon runs). How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error shows that you are attempting to connect to the PG database using the user "root", but your blog says to set it up using the postgres user and setting the password for that user. If you don't use the `-U` flag, it will default to the user you're currently using.

Something to try:

- Make sure you connect using the `-U` user flag and connect using the postgres user. That is your 'Super User' based on the blog and is usually the case with most setups. Example: `psql -U postgres -h <host/ip>`.
- Note: It is not recommended to use 'root' as a database user, even when using docker.